Laravel Custom Package Problem Call to undefined method
I am trying to create my custom package for laravel. There is my code, https://github.com/onurzdgn/cloudflare-image-api I have an problem when I using my project this package. The error is: Call to undefined method onurozdogan\CloudflareImageApi\Facades\CloudflareImageApi::upload() I thing I check everything, however I can’t find anything.

You are calling a non static upload() method statically.Check this.Have you properly registered CloudflareImageApi this calss?

The issue is in CloudflareImageApiServiceProvider for this line:
$this->app->bind('cloudflare_image_api', CloudflareImageApi::class);


You have imported Facade class,
use onurozdogan\CloudflareImageApi\Facades\CloudflareImageApi;

remove this line or import:
use onurozdogan\CloudflareImageApi\CloudflareImageApi;


I found the problem. Problem coming use onurozdogan\CloudflareImageApi\Facades\CloudflareImageApi from CloudflareImageApiServiceProvider When I delete use problem fixed

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
